# ¿Cómo se formó la expresión "pelar la pava"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, modismos, animales

La expresión [**pelar la pava**](https://dle.rae.es/pavo?m=form2#8b2LMWy) aparece en el DLE como:

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Conversar los enamorados.

Consultado el CORDE, aparece ya en 1763 (Ramón de la Cruz: *La civilización* "... ¡Qué melindre! Ahora es la ocasión perfecta de **pelar la pava** y de agarrarse de la oreja.)

En el diccionario de Dominguez (1869) aparece en el epígrafe PAVA:

> Pelar la pava: Murmurar por pasatiempo.

Y en el DLE de 1884:

> **Pava** f. Hembra del pavo. || Fuelle grande que surte de aire comprimido á cierta clase de hornos de bóveda. ||...||**Pelar la pava**. fr. fig. y fam. Tener de noche amorosas pláticas los mozos con las mozas: ellos, desde la
> calle; ellas, asomadas á rejas ó balcones.

Answer (score 0):

Esta expresión antigua esta muy relacionada con otra, "Llevar al huerto". Lugar donde espera el enamorado ó pretendiente, no necesariamente un huerto, sino un lugar acordado previamente o uno habitual que se tenga por costumbre.

La expresión "Pelar la Pava", es parte del proceso de seducción en el que acercándose poco a poco el hombre ó "macho", con ayuda de halagos, artificios y piropos, consigue que la pava, la "hembra" acabe  por "pelarse", es decir, no tenga nada con que mostrar su oposición, reparos ó inicial rechazo.

P-D. Lo de las mozas que aprovechaban para quitar las plumas al pavo o el pollo mientras eran cortejadas por el pretendiente, no tiene que ver con la expresión.

Diego

Answer (score 0):

En Argentina, la expresión "calentar la pava", seguramente derivada de la frase en cuestión, se relaciona con la práctica de tomar la infusión del mate (la pava es el utensilio utilizado para calentar el agua y luego preparar el mate) y tiene un significado un poco más fuerte. Se usa con un claro doble sentido para referirse a la excitación que provoca en la persona ser objeto de seducción, y que no siempre se ve correspondida por la obtención del favor sexual.

Inclusive existe la posibilidad de que la persona que se buscaba seducir finalmente conceda el favor sexual a alguien diferente del seductor: https://sigificadoyorigen.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/calentar-la-pava-para-que-otro-se-tome-el-mate/